# default values for interface for function properties in typescript

Tags: typescript, function, interface

I like to use typescript interfaces for function properties, But I like to use default properties as well. How can I use both?

```
export interface test_interface{
   owner: string, 
   length?: number, 
   max_players?: number,
}
const test_function = (test_props: test_interface) => {
    const x = test_props.length; //could be undefined and I want a default value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with destructuring in the function declaration.

```
export interface test_interface{
   owner: string, 
   length?: number, 
   max_players?: number,
}
const test_function = ({owner, length = 5, max_players = 4}: test_interface) => {
    const x = test_props.length; //length is 5 or whatever was passed in on the function call
}
```